# .NET AddDays issue

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

The next 2 lines adds the same amount to the same date, and the results date part is the same, but somehow the there's difference in the time part!

```
(new DateTime(2000,1,3,18,0,0)).AddDays(4535);   
(new DateTime(2000,1,3,18,0,0)).AddMonths(149);
```

you'll get a difference of 15 secs, and with both are at least roundable to days, I don't know why this happend, but it happens only with AddDays, but not AddMonths (even with thousands of months added)

---

**Edit 1**

So I've tried to make a sample project, but no luck. If I run my main project, and put the sample lines into the watches, than I get 2 separate values, if I make a fresh start, the problem is not there. The project is 3.5, c#, vs2010, win7hp x64 (proj: x86). I'm trying to reproduce it also in a fresh small project, I'll be writing back if I have it.

These are my results in the main project (copeid from watches!):

```
(new DateTime(2000, 1, 3, 18, 0, 0)).AddDays(4535).Ticks    
 634743432153600000 long

(new DateTime(2000, 1, 3, 18, 0, 0)).AddMonths(149).Ticks   
 634743432000000000 long
```

---

**Edit 2**

I've managed to narrow it down even more. We have a self-made component, panel base, we draw on it with directx. If I make that visible=false, than visible=true, than the error comes, before the visible=true (or show()), the calculation is correct. What in the world can be there, that the result gets something else of a formula where no variable is used. Culture is not affected in the component..

Comment: Could be an issue due to datatype, since AddDays takes a double.  Seems like the difference should be a lot less than 15 seconds, though. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision to see how it just approximates values.

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of the method calls to see if you get the same result? It probably won't make a difference but I'm curious.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this (on C# 4 compiler). What is your environment?

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this on C# 3 compiler either.

Comment: CurrentCulture only has to do with the way the date is displayed. I think the user is not telling us something.

Comment: Could you edit your question to make it a [short but complete program](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html); and also tell us things like which compiler version / OS etc you are using?

Comment: CurrentCulture can affect Leap Year, and machine time zone settings can affect DST calculations.  It;s possible there is a bug or miscalculation due to one of these settings.

Comment: I'll say that it's memory corruption caused by the DirectX/drivers of your graphical adaptor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of DirectX silently changing the floating-point calculation mode of the CPU to always use single precision. This is sometimes done for performance: using single precision can be quite a bit faster than using double precision. See the description of the `FpuPreserve` flag in the MSDN documentation for the DirectX [`CreateFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms859062.aspx) enumeration.

The reason others aren't able to reproduce this is because they are not doing those DirectX calls.

The argument to `AddDays` is a `double`. This value is multiplied by a scale factor to get the time in milliseconds. It is this calculation that produces the error.

Consider:

```
double value = 4535;
int scale = 86400000;
long milliseconds = (long) ((value * scale) + ((value >= 0.0) ? 0.5 : -0.5));
long milliseconds2 = (long)((float)(value * scale) + ((value >= 0.0) ? 0.5 : -0.5));
Console.WriteLine(milliseconds2 - milliseconds);
```

The expression for `milliseconds2` contains a cast to `float`, which mimics the effect of DirectX forcing single-precision calculations. This will print `15360`, exactly the difference you find.

By contrast, `AddMonths` takes an integer, and does not use any floating-point arithmetic. So the result is exact.

Answer (score 4):

Here they give the same result:

```
var d1 = (new DateTime(2000, 1, 3, 18, 0, 0)).AddDays(4535).Ticks;
var d2 = (new DateTime(2000, 1, 3, 18, 0, 0)).AddMonths(149).Ticks;
```

d1 == d2 == 634743432000000000

(the Tick is the internal "quantum" of time of DateTime. It's quite short. It's [one ten-millionth of a second](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)

I'll add that even Mono (an independent implementation of .NET) gives the same result http://ideone.com/krySY (Ideone uses mono)

Considering the more recent things you wrote, it's quite easy: memory corruption. Memory corruption can do very random things. This probably is one of those :-)

Comment: In my project it's always like that (wrong), but when I create a new project it works as expected

Comment: @user1269009 So you took the two lines I wrote, copied-pasted it VERBATIM in your old project and watched the ticks?